# JSON vs XML Benchmarks? (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, json

Is there any read/write benchmarks comparing JSON and XML for C#?

Comment: comparing them... for what? Size of payload? Speed of serialization? Speed of deserialization?

Comment: Read/Write meaning speed of deserialization and serialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain some benchmarks by embedding jgGrid in a C# web application. Try loading data in xml format and JSON format into the grid and find out how much time each takes for each of your scenarios. There is no predetermined way in taking benchmarks as one outlasts the other depending on the situations and the scenarios. But as far as I know JSON beats xml in most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core 3.0 has introduced `System.Text.Json` namespace for working with JSON. It is optimized for performance by the power of APIs like Span<T>.

With the new API, Microsoft achieved between 1.3x and 5x improvement, depending on the scenario[[1]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1801077363);